# creating mne array from csv file

Tags: python, csv, mne-python

```py
import numpy as np
import mne

csv = np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\vin.csv', delimiter=",")
print(csv)
ch_names = ['P7', 'P8', '01', '02']
sfreq = 256  # Sampling frequency
info = mne.create_info(ch_names=ch_names, sfreq=sfreq)

raw = mne.io.RawArray(csv, info,)
```

> ValueError: len(data) (16837) does not match len(info["ch_names"]) (4)

Someone help me find a solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The mne.io.RawArray(data,info) function requires data in shape (n_channels, n_times). So just transpose your data and it will work just fine.

https://mne.tools/dev/generated/mne.io.RawArray.html#mne.io.RawArray

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to ANMOL GUPTA's correct answer. Here is how you could transpose the data.

```
import numpy as np
import mne

csv = np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\vin.csv', delimiter=",")
print(csv)
ch_names = ['P7', 'P8', '01', '02']
sfreq = 256  # Sampling frequency
info = mne.create_info(ch_names=ch_names, sfreq=sfreq)

raw = mne.io.RawArray(np.transpose(csv), info)
```